# Which is the node, to which metamask is going to connect?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, metamask

I know that metamask is using Geth client, but which node is it going to connect if I select main network to connect.
Generally we use our node server and connect it with client, but how metamask works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MetaMask by default connects to [Infura](https://infura.io), but users can pick any node they want.